# How do you import Block Chain from bitcoincharts?

Tags: blockchain, import

I went to http://eu1.bitcoincharts.com/blockchain/ and downloaded the most recent build. Then I extracted it and was left with BLK0001.dat and BLK0002.dat. What is the next step? I tried replacing the current BLK files with those and performed a -rescan but that gave me a BLKINDEX  error.

My wallet data was backed up by the way. Then I moved my BLKINDEX somewhere safe so it would have to create a new one but this process didn't work because it's building BLK0002.dat still. It was super fast until it reached about 70,000 blocks left and then majorly slowed down. What is the proper way to import it? Is there a special command-line parameter that I should use to fix this?

BTW: The whole reason I had to download it separately was because Bitcoin Wallet was taking forever to download the block chain and was stuck around 97% for an eternity!

EDIT: Why does this guy even provide this website (noted above) if Blkindex needs to be created anyways?

EDIT: I gave up and decided just to use multibit and blockchain.info my wallet. I found a way to store my blockchain address on multibit so I could view it there offline.

Comment: The one thing running a Bitcoin full node gives you, is zero-trust behaviour: you don't need to trust any peer you receive data from, as everything is verified. Once you start by downloading a fully indexed blockchain, you give that up anyway. If you trust one peer enough to do the indexing for you, you can certainly live with the security model of SPV nodes like Multibit too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the not-yet-released Bitcoin.org client v0.7, you can use the -loadblock=FILE to import the blockchain from the blk0001.dat file. [Update: actually need to do two of those inline, -loadblock=blk0001.dat -loadblock=blk0002.dat in order to get both to load.]

There is a blockchain with index through block 170,000 here:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/blockchain/

That is the most complete distribution of the blockchain that I know of where the blkindex.dat is included.