# How to create a bootstrap.dat file?

Tags: blockchain, altcoin, dogecoin, bootstrap.dat

I want to create a new bootstrap.dat file for a Dogecoin. How do this kind of files are created and how can I create one? What tools should I use? any answers/links/references are appreciated. I have searched here, but I haven't found any satisfying answer. I saw this post: [Creating my own bootstrap.dat](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10381/creating-my-own-bootstrap-dat) but there is no method mentioned of putting the block in the bootstrap.dat file. Saw this post too: [How do you generate a bootstrap.dat file?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18568/how-do-you-generate-a-bootstrap-dat-file) but the tools mentioned are for Bitcoin and I'm not sure how to use them.... can anyone create a more explicit, step-by-step tutorial for doing this? something that anyone can understand? thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, a valid blockchain. If you don't have one, you may get a headstart downloading the archive gratiously posted here: http://www.reddit.com/r/dogecoin/comments/1ug62i/valid_blockchain_files_syncs_to_correct_chain/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since van der Woerdt's answer in first question you link to indicates you can simply concatenate the blk files, you can open a DOS window (if your using windows), then type

```
CD C:\Users\<my_user>\AppData\Roaming\DogeCoin
```

(if you're on Win7+)

And then

```
COPY /b blk0001.dat+blk0002.dat bootstrap.dat
```

And that would be it!

Comment: Well I didn't knew exactly what he means by "concatenating", but if it is that easy then it's awesome! thanks a lot, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Why there aren't downloads available for this? It's a waste of connections syncing over network.

Comment: @nobody: "To concatenate" means to attach sequentially after one another.

Answer (score 3):

 From Mac

1. Open terminal
2. Go to the folder where the blocks are. In this
   case Bitcoin's folder (it's the same for other bitcoin forks)

   `cd "/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/blocks/"`
3. Run this code that will concatenate all the blk files. In this case there are 4 so you would do:

   `cat blk00000.dat blk00001.dat blk00002.dat blk00003.dat blk00004.dat > bootstrap.dat`

   You can also use the * wildcard to insert them all onto the bootstrap file, or a determined range delimited by the wildcard. Like:

   `cat blk0****.dat  > bootstrap.dat`
4. Done.